# Type 1 or Type 2 error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

> 5. Merritt’s et al.’s  (2002) study included a sample size of 21 in the intervention group and 18 in the control group.   Given this information, are the researchers more likely to commit a Type I or a Type II error in this study?  Provide a rationale for your answer.

I am in need of some help in understanding how to interpret this information in this study to answer this question, I'd like help in doing so please.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Here is the self-study link and my understanding is that the study has medium strength with pvalue of p<.03 and that there were 21 in the experimental group and 18 in the control group.  I need guidance if I'm understanding this appropriately.  Thx

Comment: No, *add* the `[self-study]` tag to your question (by editing it). Then read the tag's 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck (by editing your question). We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for as I added the self-study but thanks anyway.

Comment: There is only $1$ tag on your question. It is `[hypothesis-testing]`. If you look at your question, at the bottom left you can see it. You can also see that there is no `[self-study]` tag there. Under the tag, there is a gray "edit". If you click that, you will be able to add tags & the additional information to meet our policy for such questions.

Comment: The question cannot be answered with the only information in your question.

Comment: That's a good point, @peuhp.  I suspect that's what makes this a good self-study question.

Answer (score 1):

When the null is true but you reject, you commit a type I error. When it's false but you fail to reject you commit a type II error.

Many people would simply attempt to calculate the $\alpha$ ($P(\text{reject}|H_0\text{ true})$) and $\beta$ ($P(\text{don't reject}|H_0\text{ false})$) values.

Presumably you have access to this paper (you don't give a full reference and I'm not going to guess what paper it might be), so you could likely find $\alpha$ immediately, and they may also give some estimate of a range of likely effect sizes and so on - including the sample sizes given above - from which you might be able to get get a rough idea of $\beta$.

One might then naively compare the two quantities to attempt to answer the question -- and this might even be what they want you to do though I don't think it's the right way to answer that question.

However, one cannot *actually commit* a type I error unless the null hypothesis is in fact true (similarly, to commit a type II error the null hypothesis must first be false).

Here, I think, we have the crux of the issue.

You'll need to consider the form of the null hypothesis (e.g. if they're comparing locations, is it a point null against a two-tailed alternative?) to get some idea of how likely it is that the null hypothesis could actually be true, relative to the probability that the alternative could actually be true (at any non-null effect size at all).